# Let $D$ be the disk with two disks cut out. Show that any vector field defined on $D$ has at least one equilibrium point.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, vector-fields

Let $D$ be the disk with two disks cut out, e.g. let $D$ be the set of points $(x, y)$ satisfying all of the following: $x^2 + y^2 \le 16$, $(x-2)^2+y^2 \ge 1$, $(x+2)^2+y^2 \ge 1$.  Show that any vector field that is defined on D and points towards the interior of D has at least one equilibrium point.

I have no idea how to prove this proposition. We are learning the index of vector field. It seems that the proof needs the theorem that "the index of the vector field tangent to a simple closed curve (and not vanishing on this curve) equals 1". However, I don't know how to use this.

Comment: Do you mean to be using $\geq$ in the last two inequalities?

Comment: Google "extended green's theorem." Basically you chop up the curve as to include the inner circles, then reconnect.  I also think you've left out some important information about the vector fields. As stated, $F=(1,1)$ is a vector field on $D$ with no equilibria.

Comment: @mrob Yes, they are $\ge$ in the last 2 inequalities.

Comment: There needs to be a condition on the vector field that basically says that on the boundary it can not point outside.

Comment: @LutzL Yes! I left out this condition. How to prove this proposition if I add this condition?

Comment: @mrob If the vector field points towards the interior of D, how to prove this proposition?

Comment: All your boundaries are sources for the vector field. There must be a sink inside. One should be able to do this exactly with index computations, all circles have index 1?

Comment: @LutzL Can you provide a rigorous proof using index? I don't know how to compute index in this case. Thanks.